# How to make a MySQL join conditional?

Tags: conditional-statements, inner-join, mysql-5.7

I'm using MySQL 5.7 and have three tables.  I'm only showing the relevant fields from each one to explain my problem.

```
TourHdr.id
TourHdr.paxnos

TourDet.id
TourDet.tourhdrid
TourDet.tourdate
TourDet.paxnos

DietAnal.ddtourid
DietAnal.ddtourtype
```

I want to do the following:

```
Select 'various' from TourDet
Inner join TourHdr on TourDet.tourhdrid = TourHdr.id
Inner join DietAnal on DietAnal.ddtourid = TourHdr.id and DietAnal.ddtourtype = 'TourHdr' (IF TourHdr.paxnos =  TourDet.paxnos) 

OR 

Inner join DietAnal on DietAnal.ddtourid = TourDet.id and DietAnal.ddtourtype = 'TourDet' (IF TourHdr.paxnos = TourDet.paxnos)
```

i.e. The join to DietAnal within the query is either based on TourHdr info or TourDet info depending on whether the paxnos are equal within TourHdr and TourDet or not.

I've read through many conditional join questions on Stack Overflow and MySQL forum but haven't really managed to get it to work.  I've tried IF expressions, Case expressions, AND / OR in the join on but am not managing to get the correct outcome.

The main thing to understand is that there is ALWAYS a set of records in DietAnal which match to the TourHdr.id BUT occasionally there are records that are directly connected to the TourDet.id when the paxnos differ.

Answer (score 0):

I had got as far as getting the following to work:

```
    Select 'various' from TourDet
    Inner join TourHdr on TourDet.tourhdrid = TourHdr.id
    Inner join DietAnal on DietAnal.ddtourid = TourDet.id and DietAnal.ddtourtype = 'TourDet' 
OR
DietAnal.ddtourid = TourHdr.id and DietAnal.ddtourtype = 'TourHdr'
```

That was the only one which didn't give me any syntax errors but when there was both a TourDet set of entries in the DietAnal table then I got those AND I got the TourHdr set as well.

The answer it turns out is to also include in the join the condition that the paxnos need to be either the same or different.  THAT's the bit I had not understood.  I always thought that the join could only contain fields from the tables being joined on, but it can contain any fields accessible in the query.

So my final query is :

```
    Select 'various' from TourDet
    Inner join TourHdr on TourDet.tourhdrid = TourHdr.id
    Inner join DietAnal on DietAnal.ddtourid = TourDet.id and DietAnal.ddtourtype = 'TourDet' and TourHdr.paxnos != TourDet.paxnos
OR
DietAnal.ddtourid = TourHdr.id and DietAnal.ddtourtype = 'TourHdr' and TourHdr.paxnos = TourDet.paxnos
```

This may seem simple to experienced MySQL users but I'm hoping that others with less experience will benefit from the time I had to spend getting this to work.